# Polygon chart issues (R)

Tags: r, charts, time-series, polygon

We have:

```
   date         mark_cum
1 2015-07-23   0.0000000
2 2015-07-23   0.5000000
3 2015-07-23   0.6666667
4 2015-07-24   0.6666667
5 2015-07-27   0.7500000
6 2015-07-27   0.8000000

summary(data.ru)
date                           
 Min.   :2015-07-23 00:00:00     
 1st Qu.:2015-08-24 18:00:00   
 Median :2015-09-21 00:00:00    
 Mean   :2015-09-23 16:21:00   
 3rd Qu.:2015-10-27 06:00:00    
 Max.   :2015-11-25 00:00:00  

mark_cum   
Min.   :0.0000  
1st Qu.:0.7607  
Median :0.7755  
Mean   :0.7782  
3rd Qu.:0.8090  
Max.   :0.8750
```

The idea is to construct the polygon of the following style:
[image]

Thus, we perform the following procedure:

```
hi.res.date <- approx(data.ru$date, data.ru$mark_cum, n=2000)$x
hi.res.mark <- approx(data.ru$date, data.ru$mark_cum, n=2000)$y
net.plus <- hi.res.mark; net.plus[net.plus<0.75] <- 0.75
net.minus <- hi.res.mark; net.minus[net.minus>0.75] <- 0.75
plot(data.ru3$data,rep(NA,160),type="l",ylim=c(0.75,1))
```

[image]

```
polygon(c(hi.res.date,rev(hi.res.date)),c(net.plus, rep(0,160)),col="green",border=NA)
```

And we receive a random mess where polygon doesn't take into account 0.75 border line written for `net.plus` and `net.minus` objects. What is wrong here?

[image]
P.S. Data was converted via `lubridate` into R-readable format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with this line:

```
polygon(c(hi.res.date,rev(hi.res.date)),c(net.plus, rep(0,160)),col="green",border=NA)
```

The `rep(0,160)` had to be set to `rep(0.75,160)` instead. And we receive:

[image]